# WorkManager alpha10 ListenableFuture usage

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager

I´m having some issues trying to implement the latest WorkManager-alpha10 ListenableFuture for handling process completion.

Right now I´ve the following on my **JobOrganizer** class

```
private fun enqueueDownloadWork(): ListenableFuture<Void> {
    val work = WorkManager.getInstance()
                   .beginWith(dwdTypologiesJob)
                   .then(dwdElementsJob)
                   .then(dwdAnomaliesJob)
    return work.enqueue()
}

private fun createDownloadWorkRequests() {
    dwdTypologiesJob = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<DWDAnomalyTypesJob>()
                .addTag("download_typologies_work")
                .build()
    dwdElementsJob = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<DWDElementsJob>()
                .addTag("download_elements_work")
                .build()
    dwdAnomaliesJob = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<DWDAnomaliesJob>()
                .addTag("download_anomalies_work")
                .build()
}

fun downloadData(): ListenableFuture<Void> {
    createDownloadWorkRequests()
    return enqueueDownloadWork()
}
```

And this is my call who should listen for the completion event.

```
val listenable = JobOrganizer.downloadData()
listenable.addListener({
    Log.d("Listenable", "Did something 1");
}, {
    Log.d("Listenable", "Did something 2");
})
```

I´m still missing how the Runnable and Executor works on this function. Can someone explain it?

Thanks

Comment: hi. do those listeners work for you? they seem to be called immediately after the work is scheduled on my end. i have no idea what to do

Comment: @Євген Гарастович This is probably because the executer run your code immediately so the work is already done before you add the listener. If you look at the method `enqueue` in `WorkContinuationImpl` you will see that. You can instead check for `listenable.isDone()` and base on that decide if you need a listener or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to instantiate both Runnable and Executor, for instance, when you want to execute the Runnable directly and on the current thread:

```
.addListener(
    object:Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            Log.d("Listenable", "Did something 1");
        }
    },
    object:Executor {
        override fun execute(command: Runnable?) {
            command?.run()
        }
    }
```

You can find more examples on Executors on https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor

Comment: That´s perfect, just what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For `ListenableFuture`, `Runnable` is the code that you want to run on completion and `Executor` tells it how exactly to run that code (which thread to run it on, for instance).

This should work on Kotlin:

```
listenableFuture.addListener(
    { /* Runnable: Code to run */ },
    { /* Executor: How to run */ }
)
```

Some simple executors could be as follows:

```
// Run on same thread (likely to be background thread):
{ it?.run }
// Run on main thread in android:
{ Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(it) }
// Run with delay on main thread in android:
{ Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(it, delayMillis) }
```

For instance, a usage in a `ViewModel` could look like this:

```
val dataDownloaded = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
fun beginDownload() {
    downloadData.result.addListener(
        { dataDownloaded.postValue(true) },
        { it?.run() }
    )
}
```